# ¿Cómo renumero categorías usando condicionales?

Tags: r, condiciones, else

Tengo el siguiente dataframe:

```
df1 <- data.frame(RAM = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13"),
              freq = c("1", "4", "16", "3", "5", "3","1","8","5","21","8","4","35"),
              ID = c("0","0", "3","0","0","0","0","0","0","10","0","0","13")
```

Como pueden ver, `ID` es `= 0` cuando `freq <10`, de lo contrario `ID=RAM`:

Y quiero tener esto:

```
df1 <- data.frame(RAM = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13"),
              freq = c("1", "4", "16", "3", "5", "3","1","8","5","21","8","4","35"),
              ID = c("0","0", "3","0","0","0","0","0","0","10","0","0","13"),
              RAM2 = c("3","3","3","10","10","10","10","10","10","10","13","13","13")
```

Para esto, he intentado hacerlo usando:

```
df2 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(RAM2=ifelse(ID!=0, ID, c(ID[(ID!=0)])))
```

Pero lo que obtengo apenas se parece a lo que necesito:

```
df2 <- data.frame(RAM = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13"),
              freq = c("1", "4", "16", "3", "5", "3","1","8","5","21","8","4","35"),
              ID = c("0","0", "3","0","0","0","0","0","0","10","0","0","13"),
              RAM2 = c("3","10","3","3","10","13","3","10","13","10","10","13","13")
```

Por lo que veo, `c(ID[(ID!=0)]` acumula todos los valores que no son `0` (`3`, `10` y `13` en este caso) y luego los va poniendo en ese orden en aquellos casos donde `ID =0`, sin cumplir la condición que quisiera, básicamente porque no sé como programarla. Debería decirle de algún modo que ponga `3` en `RAM2` hasta que se encuentre con `3`, `10` hasta que se encuentre con `10` y `13` hasta que encuentre `13`. ¿Cómo lo hago?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con `tidyverse`, en primer lugar, necesitamos que algunas columnas sean numéricas y no factores como son en el ejemplo de tu pregunta:

```
df1$ID <- as.numeric(as.character(df1$ID))
df1$RAM <- as.numeric(as.character(df1$RAM))
```

Lo siguiente es quedarnos con los casos que vamos a replicar, es decir, filtramos los `ID` mayores a 0:

```
df1 %>% 
  filter(ID > 0) -> casos
```

Y finalmente, agrupamos por fila y buscamos en `casos` el `RAM` menor igual que le corresponde a cada fila:

```
df1 %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(RAM2=casos$RAM[min(which(RAM <= casos$RAM))])

Source: local data frame [13 x 4]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 13 x 4
     RAM freq     ID  RAM2
   <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1 1         0     3
 2     2 4         0     3
 3     3 16        3     3
 4     4 3         0    10
 5     5 5         0    10
 6     6 3         0    10
 7     7 1         0    10
 8     8 8         0    10
 9     9 5         0    10
10    10 21       10    10
11    11 8         0    13
12    12 4         0    13
13    13 35       13    13
```